# Link a controller to a dynamically added view

Tags: ember.js

Hi and thanks a lot for your answers! 
I am trying to understand Ember and its structure.

And this is where I am stuck with : I have a view that can be added anywhere and anytime in my web-app (modal view). I want to link this view with a specific controller to handle event, state and other behaviors.

But I didn't find how it is possible! Is this an error in the structure of my application or is it a problem that comes from somewhere else? (me?)

Here is the relevant part of the code.

**/views/post_news_popup.js**

```
App.PostNewsPopupView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: '_post-news',
    close: function() { /*...*/ },
    save: function() { /*...*/ }
});
```

**index.html**

```
{{view App.PostNewsPopupView}}

...

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_post-news">
    <form {{ action "save" on "submit"}}>
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name" placeholder="Fill in a name..."}}
        {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="description" placeholder="Fill in a description..."}}
        <button {{action 'close'}}>Cancel</button>
        <button>Post news</button>
    </form>
</script>
```

**controllers/post_news_controller.js**

```
App.PostNewsPopupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        close:function() { /*...*/ },
        save:function() { /*...*/ }
    }
 });
```

I didn't find the way to link PostNewsPopupController to PostNewsPopupView. 
I tried a lot of things, but neither functions of controller nor functions of view were called.

I know that controllers are automatically set when browsing to a route, but here there is no specific route for this and I don't want to put all that code in ApplicationController.

Thank you for helping me and sorry if question is... stupid! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following code to the route connected to the template, in which you are currently using the view helper (i don't its name :-):

**Add this to your Route:**

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);

    this.render('postNewsPopup', {
      outlet: 'modalOutlet',
    });
}
```

**Add the outlet to the template where you want the view to be added:**

```
{{outlet modalOutlet}}
```

**This will render the PostNewsPopupView into the modalOutlet connected to the PostNewsPopupController.**

**Further informations:**

The render method takes more arguments. Here is a full blown example of the render method:

```
this.render('your', {   // the template/view to render
  into: 'index',          // the template to render into
  outlet: 'someOutlet',       // the name of the outlet in that template
  controller: this.controllerFor("another")  // the controller to use for the template
});
```

This would render a view of type **App.YourView** into the **index template** with the outlet named **someOutlet**. The view will be connected to a the controller instance for **App.AnotherController**.

Comment: Both of your solutions are working !! I did not know such a solution, but I think it will be very helpful for the continuation of my web application! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution sounds more "accepted" by EmberJS too. Indeed previous solution was not well detected in [Ember Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi). This one seems to be a bit more difficult, but is really better. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check whether the following is helpful. Specify the context when declaring view.

```
App.PostNewsPopupView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: '_post-news',
    controller:App.PostNewsPopupController.create()
});

App.PostNewsPopupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        close:function() { /*...*/ },
        save:function() { /*...*/ }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Both of your solutions are working !! I tried something like that but I think my controller was declared after my view. I changed the order of the dependencies and it is now working as expected ! Thanks for your very helping answer !

Comment: This way you will have no access to the controller and therefore you can't assign content to it (not without hacks). So this looks pretty useless to me.

Comment: Indeed, after some further reading/coding/watching... Your solution was indeed the most "advanced" one and the most recommended for its flexibility! 
I migrated for yours then. Thanks a lot for extra explanations, too!